# schema.org microdata issue with SearchAction form

Tags: html, forms, get, schema.org, microdata

I try put meta in myhtml code

for example I want do it for my search engine with offical google code:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
  <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.example.com/"/>
  <form itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction">
    <meta itemprop="target" content="https://query.example.com/search?q={search_term_string}"/>
    <input itemprop="query-input" type="text" name="search_term_string" required/>
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

THis is my problem.

The local search engine in my website use root url...

for example  http://example.com/obama

but the code done it something like this when I submit it:

http://example.com/?search_term_string=obama

how can remove '?search_term_string=' without bad effect on the code?

Comment: I don’t understand your problem. The snippet contains `https://query.example.com/search?q={search_term_string}` as target search URL. Where is `http://example.com/?search_term_string=obama` coming from? And how’s `http://example.com/obama` relevant?

Comment: thanks. I solved it with htaccess ...infact it wasn't a microdata issue